# Creating PDF using script does not have formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, google-sheets-api

I am creating a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script which I am then emailing as a pdf. Problem is my script adjusts the column widths but this formatting is not reflected in the pdf document created.

Going through the process manually attaching the spreadsheet does not lose the formatting.

```
sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, 5);
var ss_ID = spreadsheet.getId();
var myfile = DriveApp.getFileById(ss_ID);

var mydraft = GmailApp.createDraft("emailaddress", "My Subject" ,"My Details ",
{ attachments: [myfile], name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'}
);
mydraft.send();
```

Pdf sent by email via script has all columns set to standard width.

Expect column widths to be set to the widths defined in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Simon! Could you please post the code part that controls spreadsheet export as pdf? Judging from your sample, you simply send the spreadsheet as attachment (as .gsheet)

Comment: That is correct, but the GmailApp converts the spreadsheet to a pdf, in that stage the formatting was getting lost. Since posting this question, I now find that the pdf is being formatted correctly, i.e the issue may have been fixed.

Comment: Simon, indeed it does! My bad - kind of curious, though, have you tried another run [re:"pdf is being formatted correctly"]? If so, possibly the issue is related to latency, maybe add a `sleep()` call or open the spreadshet with `SpreadsheetApp` and check if the col width is updated before sending the email

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above the issue dissappeared. Now have added the `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in case it should reappear.

```
   sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, 5);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var ss_ID = spreadsheet.getId();
    var myfile = DriveApp.getFileById(ss_ID);
    var mydraft = GmailApp.createDraft("emailaddress", "My Subject" ,"My Details ",
    { attachments: [myfile], name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'}
    );
    mydraft.send();
```